# How to set connection string for whole application in c# windows Application?

Tags: c#

datadirectory is not working for connection string in c# windows application in my project.
I already tried this but its not work.

Answer (score 3):

you can add it in app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Dbconnection" 
       connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=OnlineShopping ; Integrated Security=True" ;
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

in code Add reference to add System.Configuration and read like this:-

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

or in web.config, you can add it **appSettings**:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="ApplicationTitle" value="Sample Console Application" />
   <add key="ConnectionString"
       value="Server=localhost;Database=Northwind;Integrated
              Security=false;User Id=sa;Password=;" />
</appSettings>
```

and read in code like this:

```
 ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
```